# Generar código según varios criterios

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un programa que genera un código único por ejemplar que añado a la BD. Él código lo genera así:

```
$codejemplares = count($ejem);
$codejemplares = $codejemplares + "1";
$codejemplares = str_pad($codejemplares, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);


$codcentro = $_POST["centro_id"];
$codejem = str_pad($totalejem, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

// Código de 8 dígitos dividido en 3 parámetros
    // Param 1: 1 digito: ID Centro
    // Param 2: 5 digitos: Número de ejemplares total
    // Param 3: 2 digitos: Número de ejemplares vinculado al ID Libro

    // Ejemplo secuencia: 30000101

$codigo = $codcentro . $codejemplares . $codejem;
```

La primera parte del código la genera el ID del centro. (Max 9 centros)
La segunda parte del código la genera el número total de ejemplares +1. (Max 99.999 ejemplares)
La tercera parte del código la genera el número total de ejemplares vinculado a un libro. (Max 99 ejemplares a un libro)

Me gustaría actualizar este código para agrandarlo. Necesitaría que:

El centro siga siendo el ID pero contenga mínimo 2 dígitos. Los ID menores de 10 añadir un cero. (99 centros)

Los ejemplares vinculados a un libro sean de 3 dígitos (999 ejemplares).

El código del medio no tendría que modificarlo.

¿Cómo podría actualizar este código y que no me de problemas de duplicado?

Además, tengo ya unos 450 ejemplares con el código asignado del modelo que quiero actualizar. Sería posible actualizar los códigos antiguos masivamente? Tenia planteado echarle un rato y modificarlos manualmente en la DB, pero si existe forma de hacerlo masivamente mejor.

Muchas gracias!

Añado el código final arreglado que he hecho en base a la respuesta:

```
function conversor($n){
        if(strlen($n)==8){
            $fixcentro=substr($n,0,1);
            $fixejem=substr($n,1,5);
            $fixtejem=substr($n,6,2);

            $donecentros = str_pad($fixcentro, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $doneejem = str_pad($fixejem, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $donetejem = str_pad($fixtejem, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

            $n = $donecentros . $doneejem . $donetejem;
        }
        return $n;
    }

$fix = new SQLMan();
$fix->tablename = "ejemplar";   
$fixejem= $fix->select();

foreach ($fixejem as $fe) {

    $newcode = conversor($fe->fields["codigo"]);
    $newid = $fe->fields['id'];

        $ze = new SQLMan();
        $ze->tablename = "ejemplar";

        // $a->in_test = true;
        $ze->update(array(
            "codigo"=>$a->is_string($newcode)
            ),"id=".$newid);
        unset($ze);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mientras ningún centro tenga el código 0, no tendrás problemas de duplicados porque estás añadiendo un dígito más a tu codificación, únicamente modificando esta línea:

```
$codejem = str_pad($totalejem, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Con esta función podrías transformar los códigos antiguos a nuevos:

```
function conversor($n){
    if(strlen($n)==8){
        $codcentro=substr($n,0,1);
        $codejemplares=substr($n,1,5);
        $totalejem=substr($n,6,2);
        $codejem = str_pad($totalejem, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $n = $codcentro . $codejemplares . $codejem;
    }
    return $n;
}
```

O, también, algo más corta:

```
function conversor($n){
    if(strlen($n)==8)
        $n = substr($n,0,6).'0'.substr($n,6,2);
    return $n;
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes @David JP basándome en tu respuesta he modificado el código para añadir otra cifra también al parámetro intermedio. Todo funciona correctamente y he podido actualizar todos los códigos sin problema. Muchas gracias!